# how to setup a loader

Tags: qt, qml, loader

I want to setup a loader to open a QML file; but is seems doesn't work:

```
 Button{//Below Right
        width:profilePicture.width/2
        height:profilePicture.width/2
        x:profilePicture.x+profilePicture.width
        y:profilePicture.y+profilePicture.height
        contentItem: Image {
            source: "Images/freecoins.png"
            anchors.fill: parent
            Rectangle{
                anchors.fill:parent
                radius: this.width
                border.color: "yellow"
                border.width: 2
                color: "transparent"
            }
        }
        onClicked: popUpFreeCoinsloader.active = true
        Loader{
            id: popUpFreeCoinsloader
            source: "PopUpFreeCoins.qml"
            active: false
            focus: true
        }
}
```

also I wanna set the properties of that QML file, but don't know how to do.
for example, I have property int a and property int b that are the window width and height, how can I initialize them in loader, as initializing in component like this?:

```
Component{
    PopUP{a:100; b:200}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "is seems doesn't work" since the Loader works normally for me. The code should work. An easy example:

Main.qml:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Button{
        text: "button"
        onClicked: loader.active = true
    }

    Loader{
        id: loader
        active: false
        source: "Testy.qml"
        focus: true
    }
}
```

Testy.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle{
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "red"
}
```

I suspect your PopUpFreeCoins.qml is not instantiated correctly or has like zero width and height.

As to your second question, use `sourceComponent` [(link)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#sourceComponent-prop)

It is easy to see in my example:

Modified Main.qml:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Button{
        text: "button"
        onClicked: loader.active = true
    }

    Loader{
        id: loader
        active: false
        // load customized component
        sourceComponent: rect
        focus: true
    }

    //customized component
    Component {
      id: rect

      Testy {
        //customized values
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

Or in your example:

```
Loader{
    id: popUpFreeCoinsloader
    sourceComponent: popUp
    active: false
    focus: true
}

Component{
     id: popUp
     PopUP{a:100; b:200}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your component is a separate window, then it might need to be explicitly shown after loading.

I.e. loading will just make the object available to the program, but it will be invisible until shown, much like the `visible` property of your `Window` makes sure it is shown.

As for value transfer, you have two options

1. At load time

   ```
   Loader {
       onLoaded: {
           item.a = 123;
           item.b = 456;
       }
   }
   ```

Here the values will be written into the loaded item's properties, i.e. this is an assignment.

2. With a `Binding` element

   ```
   Loader {
       id: myLoader
   }
   Binding {
       target: myLoader.item
       property: "a"
       value: 123
   }
   ```

Here we have a property binding, i.e. the item's property is bound to the value, with automatic updating and all the usual property binding behavior